# nginx proxying POST requests to REMOTE server + SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

Due to some limitations and firewalls, it seems I need to use a proxy via nginx. Nginx is already running with SSL + certs.

I've tested the following successfully, but now I'm wondering if it will use the current certificate settings on my nginx configs in two-way ssl, or if I need the "proxy_ssl" configurations (below).

```
location /remoteapi/ {      
    if ($remote_addr != x.y.z.y) {
       return 403; #block anything NOT from the internal IP. 
       #(No one else should use proxy)
    }
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_set_header Origin $proxy_host; # this should be nginx server url
    proxy_pass https://www.remoteapiexample.com;
  }
}
```

Do I need to set these proxy SSL parameters? My nginx is already up and running with SSL, won't it make the requests properly with SSL anyway? There's only going to be specific requests POST/GET from the internal server to the remote website with the same certs.

```
#proxy_ssl_certificate src.crt;
#proxy_ssl_certificate_key srv.key;
#proxy_ssl_ciphers TLSv1.2;
#proxy_ssl_password_file keyfile.pz;
#proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate root.crt;
#proxy_ssl_verify on;
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to use Nginx? [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) would seem to be a better match for your requirements.

Comment: Yeah, this is how I deployed everything in multiple servers.

Comment: That doesn't sound like _must_, it sounds like you could choose appropriate software but you'd prefer to use Nginx. Must would be more like 
corporate policy of lack of admin credentials.

Comment: its a lack of control of the hosting enviro. Why would nginx not forward things to a remote site? That's how its upstream + loadbalancing stuff works in a way on an internal network.

Comment: You should probably try it and see what happens, the post if you have a problem.

Comment: I guess I wanted to check on things first. But yes I did try it now. So I will update my question.